# What more can be said about $\max_{v^\mathsf{T} v=1} \frac{v^\mathsf{T} B v}{v^\mathsf{T} A v}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, perturbation-theory

Assume we have a positive semidefinite matrix $A$. Another matrix $B$ is equal to $A$ except it's $i$th row and$i$th column is zeros and element $B_{ii}=(n-1)A_{ii}$. i.e.
\begin{align}
B&=A-e_i e_i^T A- A e_i e_i^T+(n-1) A_{ii} e_i e_i^T\cr
\end{align}

So, $B$ is also positive semidefinite. Now, my question is what can we say about the following quantity?
\begin{align}
r=\max_{v^\mathsf{T} v=1} \frac{v^\mathsf{T} B v}{v^\mathsf{T} A v} \leq \frac{\lambda_{max}\big(B\big)}{\lambda_{min}\big(A\big)}
\end{align}
Edit: If it's the case that we encounter the division zero problem, we can assume that matrices are positive definite.
I mean I need ( and must ) use information available about $B$ to compute this quantity.
What I have done: Based on the comment by @Michael and answer by @user7530   , the above quantity is equal to $\lambda_{max}(A^{-1}B)$. So we have
\begin{align}
A^{-1}B&=I-A^{-1}e_i e_i^T A- A^{-1} A e_i e_i^T+(n-1) A_{ii} A^{-1} e_i e_i^T\cr
r=\lambda_{max}(A^{-1}B)&=\lambda_{max}\Big(I-(A^{-1})_{*i}A_{i*}- e_i e_i^T+(n-1) A_{ii} (A^{-1})_{ii} e_i e_i^T\Big)\cr
r=\lambda_{max}(A^{-1}B)&=1-\lambda_{max}\Big((A^{-1})_{*i}A_{i*}+ e_i e_i^T-(n-1) A_{ii} (A^{-1})_{ii} e_i e_i^T\Big)
\end{align}
I don't know how to proceed. Even if we can find a tight bound is very good for me.
I want to use this in an optimization problem.

Comment: If $A$ is truly semidefinite, then this question is not entirely well-posed, because $r$ sometimes involves a division by zero.

Comment: Atleast one eigen value of a postivie semidefinite matrix is zero. But maximizing  $v^\mathsf{T} B v$ doesn't coincide with with minimum eigen value of  $B$. Also, we can assume that matrices are positive definite in this question. I update the question.

Comment: My point still stands: you were asking about maximizing a function which is not defined on the whole sphere over the sphere. Even excluding the null space of $A$ from the problem, you can't be sure that the situation is nice enough that the supremum of the quotient is not just $+\infty$. Anyway, if $A$ is actually positive definite, then this is closely related to the generalized eigenvalue problem, in the same way that the Rayleigh quotient is related to the standard eigenvalue problem.

Comment: If you assume $A$ is positive definite you can write $A=C^TC$ for an invertible matrix $C$.  Then use the change of variables $w=Cv$ and $v=C^{-1}w$ to get $\frac{v^TBv}{v^TAv} = \frac{w^T(C^{-1})^TBC^{-1}w}{w^Tw}$, and so the maximum is the largest singular value of $(C^{-1})^TBC^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you,@lan, Could you please give more information about when the quotient is $+\inf$?. It's some how relates to Rayleigh quotient, but I want to know something more specific about the result.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. But the what is the relation of $\lambda_{max}\big( (C^{-1})^T B C^{-1}\big)$ to eigen values of matrix $A$. This isn't give us any information about the original matrix $A$ directly and is very expensive to compute for my problem. More importantly, I feel it is redundant to compute because we already computed eigenvalues of matrix $A$.

Comment: You wanted to know the answer ot maximziing $\frac{v^T Bv}{v^TAv}$.  The answer is hte sinular value of $(C^{-1})^TBC^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes. I mean I must use information we have about $B$ (and $A$ which is only positive definiteness) to compute $r$. About your previous comment, $v^T v = \omega^T (C^{-1})^T C^{-1} \omega = 1$, then again can we say it is the largest eigen value, becuase we no longer have $w^T w=1$ for the new quotient.

Comment: Maximizing $\frac{v^T Bv}{v^TAv}$ over vectors $v$ with $||v||=1$ is the same as maximziing over all $v \neq 0$, since we can scale $v$ by any nonzero number and it does not change the fraction.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about why this solution is not satisfactory? You have an explicit algorithm you can now run to compute the solution to your optimization problem. Are you hoping for something more efficient than taking the SVD? Do you have any reason to believe something more efficient exists?

Comment: As I edited in the question, $A^{-1}B$ is completely related to $A$. The solution $\lambda_{max}\Big(A^{-1}B\Big)$is not satisfactory, Because it doesn't take this into account and solved a more general problem when $B$ is not related to $A$. It's not about hoping for something more efficient than SVD. It's about using all information we have.

Comment: Fine, but that's kind of like saying "don't use the quadratic formula to solve $x^2+7x+9=0$, because it's not using the full information that $b=c-2$." Sometimes more information helps, sometimes it does not.

Comment: And in any case, the last line of your edited question has a formula only in terms of $A$ and not $B$, which is what you want right?

Answer (score 3):

The key is to see that whenever $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}B$, $\frac{v^TBv}{v^TAv}$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. This follows from
\begin{align*}
A^{-1}Bv &= \lambda v\\
Bv &= \lambda Av\\\
v^TBv &= \lambda v^TAv.
\end{align*}

One important area where this identity shows up is the differential geometry of surfaces, where it proves that the principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of the Weingarten map.

Now the optimality condition of your maximization problem (notice that you are free to ignore the constraint, away from $\|v\|=0$) is

$$\frac{2Bv}{v^TAv} - \frac{2Avv^TBv}{(v^TAv)^2}=0$$
or
$$A^{-1}Bv = \left(\frac{v^TBv}{v^TAv}\right)v,$$
so an optimal $v$ is necessarily an eigenvector of $A^{-1}B$, and we saw above that all eigenvectors will satisfy this equation. Therefore the solution to your optimization problem is the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$ (or equivalently, the largest generalized eigenvalue $Bv = \lambda Av$).

Comment: Thank you @user7530. But  $B$ is part of $A$. The question is how can we relate it to something only about $A$? As said in question to use all information we have about the problem.

Comment: @user85361 What exactly are you trying to do? If you have the actual numbers for $A$ you can easily compute $A^{-1}B$ and its eigenvalues.

Comment: No I don't have actual numbers. I want to use the result in an optimization problem. Also, my main concern is about efficiency. That's why I want to use all information available.